# Saturation of controlled voltage source

Tags: mosfet, driver, saturation

I have simulated a voltage controlled current source based on the article in the link; the LTspice file is also attached.

I think my MOSFETs are saturated, so I get almost constant current on the output. What could be done to open the swing of the current on the inductor so given a ±1 V sine input I get ±10 mA on the load?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nq8COPZHYdB_n_qWaaSGVOcekv5TVxR1/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10UwF0Qx0qxELL1Ga2FxmhsKcIMpFE3u_/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! _”I think my MOSFETs are saturated”_ Measure and find out!

Comment: The files apparently require permission to access. The maximum current is going to be less than Vm or Vp  divided by 1kΩ, so you might have to scale the resistors etc.

Comment: I would suggest using a op-amp with sufficient output current to drive a 10mA load directly... Way simpler

Comment: I never liked the schemes where the op-amp's power rails are used as part of the signal path.  Not that it doesn't work, it does.  It just seems inelegant to me for some reason.  Of course, the PSRR and headroom to the rails will be a consideration, and it obviates the use of decoupling capacitors on the rails.

Answer (score 1):

SPICE is very tricky for novices, since they have no feel for what aspects of functionality are reasonable to model in an op-amp.

Many op-amp models don't model the voltage supply pin behavior well, since almost no one uses op-amps that way.

You'll want to use a basic direct-coupled audio push-pull output stage, with a current sense resistor and feedback loop to control the current. With proper compensation, this will work very well, and have high bandwidth.

You also should consider that the rate of change of current on an inductor is determined by the voltage across the inductor. If the current is commanded to change too quickly, the output voltage will saturate at either supply rail.